# How do I access the nested properties of an array in Loopback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, loopback, ecmascript-2016

here,
res = Array of results retrieved

```
res = [ Object, Object, Object... Object ]
```

Each Object looks like this:

```
Object{
    "userId": "ab1ce",
    "groupId": "a1de2"
}
```

Now, the results has an array of objects like this, how do i access the userId present in those Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using it in loopback you can use the **inq** property in the **where** clause so as to search something from inside the Array
e.g:

```
modelname.method({ where: { "property": { inq [ res.property  ] } } }, (err, res) => {
    if(err) { return console.error(err);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The **inq** operator checks whether the *value* of the specified property matches any of the values provided in an ***array***. The general syntax is:

```
{where: { property: { inq: [val1, val2, ...]}}}
```

Where:

**property** is the name of a property (field) in the model being queried.

**val1, val2, and so on,** are literal values in an **array**.

***Example*** of ***inq*** operator:

```
Posts.find({where: {id: {inq: [123, 234]}}}, 
    function (err, p){... });
```

Answer is Specific to Loopback.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
res.forEach(function(obj){
 console.log(obj.userId);
});
```

Comment: What if I want to store the result data into a variable in a JSON fromat?

Comment: step1: learn javascript basics, step2: try something

Answer (score 1):

`res` is an array of objects so to access one object you have to use something like this:

```
res[index];
```

where `index` is a subscript that tell which item of the array you want. Since arrays are 0-indexed, `index` should be in the range `[0, res.length - 1]`.

Then when you access an item from the array `res`, you'll get an object that you can access using either these ways:

```
res[index].key;
// OR
res[index]["key"];
```

where `key` is the name of the property of that object. So to get the userId of the first object in the array use this:

```
var mySecondObject = res[1]; // 0 is the first, 1 is the second ...
var theId = mySecondObject.userId; // or theId = mySecondObject["userId"];
```

or in one line like this:

```
var theId = res[1].userId;
```

**Note:** `res` is an array, you can loop through it using a lot of different ways (`for` loop, `forEach` ...) [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript) is an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For each item of the array, 0 to n, you can get the object from the array and then access it's attributes.

for example `res[0].userId` would get you the userId of the first item.

you should probably read some kind of Javascript primer manual to get the basica, there're a few listed in the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) or [this one](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is a good one